# Stable rank of finite rings

Tags: algebraic-k-theory

Has any finite ring (not necessarily commutative) always stable rank 2 ? How do you prove that or does it follow from something ? May be this question is trivial but I'm not familiar with K-theory.

Answer (score 3):

Finite is semilocal, and semilocal rings always have stable rank 1 (even if non-commutative), as shown in Lemma 6.4 and Corollary 6.5 of Bass' "[K-Theory and stable algebra](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02684689)".